# Why is the Legendre symbol not defined for $p = 2$ (even prime)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Why is the Legendre symbol not defined for $p = 2$ (even prime) ?

According to the definition of the Legendre symbol $$\left(\frac a p\right)$$ it is defined for an odd prime $p$ only. Even thus the case where $p = 2$ is an even prime is not particularly interesting, why are the restriction made that  $p$ must be an odd prime ?

Source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Comment: The answer is mostly because Legendre's original formulation for the symbol was $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}, which isn't necessarily well-defined for the case of even p since it creates a fractional power.

Comment: You mean we get $a^{\frac 1 2} = \sqrt{a}$ and we dont want to work with non-integers in number-theory ? According to the new definition, why not change the domain to include $p=2$ ?

Comment: that's essentially what the Jacobi symbol is (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol), but again it only applies to odd integers (not composites), and Kronecker symbol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol) generalizes it to all integers.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a way to define it that helps to formulate [the law of quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity), which is what Legendre was trying to do [when introducing his symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

As I'm sure you observed, every $a$ is a quadratic residue mod 2, but 2 is not a quadratic residue modulo every modulus, or modulo every prime modulus.  So computing when 2 is a quadratic residue mod $p$ is interesting (for odd primes $p$), but computing when $p$ is a quadratic residue mod 2 is trivial.

**Added:** If we wanted to define the Legendre symbol for $p=2$, just for the sake of completeness, the natural definition would be $(a/p) = 1$ for $a$ odd and $(a/p) = 0$ for $a$ even.  It's important that we keep in mind that quadratic reciprocity only works with two odd primes, so omitting $p=2$ from the definition of the Legendre symbol is justifiable for avoiding any confusion on that point.  What this does "make work" is the multiplicative character of the symbol, i.e. $(ab/p) = (a/p)(b/p)$ now also when $p=2$.

Answer (score 4):

The Legendre symbol $(a/p)$ is a multiplicative character of the finite field of order $p$, $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Since it maps onto $\pm 1$ it is of order $2$. A multiplicative character of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ has to have order dividing $p-1$, so the Legendre symbol is only properly defined when $p$ is odd.

You can make an arbitrary definition for $p = 2$, but without the interesting properties of a multiplicative character, your definition is unlikely to be mathematically interesting.

Comment: its still a multiplicative character mod 2 - it just has order 1 instead of 2 since it wont map to $-1$.